# Gam regression in r yields strange error message

Tags: r, gam

I am trying to run a gam on a data frame containing a numerical (outcome) variable and two factors.

Here is a sample:

```
df = structure(list(ProviderCount = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0",
">0"), class = "factor"), AdmCharge = c(12889.32, 51858.43, 9957.34,
30164.17, 146750.17, 9653.39, 27547.83, 7573.13, 70912.57, 2400,
39719.79, 63282.82, 44386.1, 31832.86, 7578.46, 34729.19, 38800.62,
15985.41, 450, 24213.66), LastStage = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L,
2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3.1", "3.2", "4", "5"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA,
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The command to run the model is:

```
model1 = gam(AdmCharge ~ s(LastStage + ProviderCount),
          data = df)
```

and the error message is:

```
Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) :
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(xx) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In Ops.factor(xx, shift[i]) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

I have searched for this message and I thought I fixed everything: no NA's, characters as factors..

Any idea?

Comment: I think the first argument in `s` has to be a numeric variable https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-March/232580.html

Comment: Addition is not defined for factor variables (such as `LastStage` and `ProviderCount`). That's the primary cause of the error.